# Is it correct to say "Mary can file this form against Mike to New York family court for divorce"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Oxford dictionary says "**to file for divorce/bankruptcy**" generally.

But it doesn't have a complete structure that help us to express ideas completely.

Do  we have a structure like this:

**to file (a legal form, etc) + against + sb/sth + to + a court + for + divorce/bankruptcy etc.**?

or

**to file (a legal form, etc) + against + sb/sth + with + a court + for + divorce/bankruptcy etc.**?

For example, you and your friend are helping Mike and Mary to end their marriage. Mary signed a specific form and she needs to send that form to a specific court for divorce.

Can you talk to your friend, "**Mary can file this form against Mike to New York family court for divorce**" rather than just saying "**Mary can file for divorce**"?

Saying "**Mary can file for divorce**" doesn't give a listener complete detail of the situation.

Comment: If your friend knows who Mary is married to, and in what legal jurisdiction she and her husband live, why do you need to state what your friend already knows?

Comment: I am finding "Mary can file this form against Mike to New York family court for divorce" too unwieldy. Looking at your rep, you surely can better reconstruct the sentence. Here is a suggestion, "Mary can file this form for divorce with New York family court against Mike(respondent)". Even then—you can file a complaint against sb, I don't know if you can submit a form against sb. The longer sentence would be "Mary can file this form for divorce with New York family court making Mike the respondent". This is all hypothetical of course. I wouldn't want to be the cause for peoples' divorces.

Comment: As usual, Tom, you are trying to cram too much information into one sentence. It's like a badly-written play or story, in which the author tries to give the audience/reader information by having one character tell another things that they already know. "Mary can submit this form to the New York Family Court." (Your friend knows that she is divorcing Mike.)